# File upload issue in Rails 2.3.5 using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a Rails 2.3.5 application which has file upload functionality using paperclip. When I upload a file, the first time everything works fine. But the second time I try I get the following error message:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::Encoding
```

From the trace it looks like an issue with form_authenticity_token.

```
<% form_for @import, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| -%>
    <ul>
        <li><%= f.label :source, "Select a file to import" %></li>
        <li><%= f.file_field :source %></li>

        <%= submit_tag 'Submit' -%>         
    </ul>
<% end -%>
```

If I clear the browser cache, I can get it working again. So I guess this is something related to session/tempfile etc. I just dont know what exactly :)
Is there something I am missing here?
Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Abhilash

Comment: Do you have "protect_from_forgery" uncommented in ApplicationController?

Comment: Can you please post the entire trace. I have a few ideas but I want to make sure. Do you have any caching enabled for the page?

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to this fixed ticket https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3666-messageverifier-and-rails-235-with-ruby-187, upgrade your rails will probably sort it out.